# Zend Server Community Edition .htaccess issue

Tags: php, apache, zend-server, zend-server-ce

I am a new user of Zend Server. For some reason Apache is not reading my htaccess file in the project folder. please check my settings:

Document root:C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\

project folder: C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\project1\website\

htaccess path: C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2\htdocs\project1\website.htaccess

Example to of rewrite rule in htaccess:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-]*)-([0-9]*)-([0-9]*)\.php$  /project1/website/index.php?cat=$2&page=$3 [L]
```

changes in httpd.conf file:

LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

```
<Directory "C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride ALL
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

The index page is working fine
http://   localhost/project1/website/

Comment: Why don't you just use general rewrite mod instead of rewriting specific request?

Comment: This is an old system. my question is more about making it work within zend server. It is working very well on any linux server so far as well as on in wampp, xampp.

Comment: After two hours of testing and bugging. I found probably the answer. I reinstalled the zend server and put it on my D:/zend_server and all worked with the same setting as before. so I think the issue was in the folder path: C:\Program Files\Zend\Apache2/htdocs. "Program Files" folder have white space in folder name. C:\zend_server\Zend\Apache2/htdocs. worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

You should go to httpd.conf file in your apchachi folder/conf and change AllowOverride none to AllowOverride ALL after restart apachi server.Hope it work.