# URL Rewriting not working on Zend Server Community Edition 5.3.9

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, zend-server-ce

**To @All, Nobody is here to answer this question?**

I have tried my below problem with following SO question [Zend Server Community Edition .htaccess issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13878243/zend-server-community-edition-htaccess-issue) but could not get success. That's why posting my details question here as follows:

I am having a very serious issue with `Zend Community Server Edition (ZendServer-CE-php-5.3.9-5.6.0-SP1-Windows_x86)`.

Everything is working fine but not `URL Rewrtiting`.

I have following things set up in my `httpd.conf` file of `Apache` folder on Windows 7

I have enabled `mod_rewrite` module in `httpd.conf` file like

> LoadModule rewrite_module modules/mod_rewrite.so

Below is my Document Root for my all projects

> DocumentRoot "D:/projects/"

and its related `<Directory>` settings like

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
    #Order deny,allow
    #Deny from all
</Directory>

<Directory D:/projects>
    Options Indexes +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride All
    #Order deny,allow
    #Deny from all
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
```

I have `.htaccess` setup in httpd.conf is as below

```
<FilesMatch "^\.ht">
    Order allow,deny
    Deny from all
    Satisfy All
</FilesMatch>
```

Now, I have following path of my `test` folder for `URL Rewriting`.

```
D:/projects/url


D:/projects/url/.htaccess
```

and content of .htaccess file is as below

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^news news.php
RewriteRule ^news/id/(.*)/article/(.*) news.php?id=$1&article=$2

D:/projects/url/news.php
```

In news.php file (when I specify it on addressbar like localhost:/url/news.php it does not works and giving below error message

> Forbidden
>
> You don't have permission to access /url/news on this server.

code in news.php file is as below

```
$path = $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'];
echo $path."<br/>";

//below is for http://localhost:<PORT>/url/news/id/62/article/abc
if(isset($_GET['id']) && isset($_GET['article']))
{
    echo $_GET['id']."<br/>";
    echo $_GET['article'];
}
```

Any guidance will be appreciated.

**To @All, Nobody is here to answer this question?**

Comment: @All Nobody is here to answer this question?